# Google custom search apiGet the total number search results by country

Tags: api

I'd like to get the Totla Number Search Results  for a specific term in a specific country
I can't get it throw google custom search api i only get the entire web number search result 
I thought about scrapping google but i don't know about legaly issues

Regards
Frank

Comment: I live in France i don't know if it's legal to parse google to get some information about number search results